# Searching a file for a string and printing the lines containing the string

Tags: bash, grep

I want to search a file line by line for the string `12345678`, and print the full line(s) containing the string.

For instance, if the input file was

```
09298213 YYYY
12345678 NYNY
12173217 YYNN
```

Then the output should be

```
12345678 NYNY
```

Comment: Did  you hear about `grep`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just looking for `grep`. Specifically, in your case, the following will do the job:

```
grep '12345678' yourfile
```

and you can place with all `grep`'s options that you like to print some context lines, to add coloring, and to do other fancy stuff.

Comment: `to suppress coloring` The default is not to color [grep.c source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/grep.c#L85). The coloring on most distributions comes from a shell alias. ; )

Comment: I feel stupid. The intent was to assign the return statement to a variable. Didn't think about assigning the grep statement to the variable. Thanks haha